# git networking for small team

Tags: networking, ubuntu, user-management, git

I'm trying to set up git for my programming team.

My setup is:

```
1. example.com (Ubuntu server)
IP: 192.168.1.2 (public: xxx.yyy.yyy.zzz)
main git repository in /var/www/testgit
user: mot (root)

2. host2, Ubuntu
IP: 192.168.1.101
git clone of main repo in ~/public_html/testgit1
user: nairda

3. host3, Ubuntu
IP: 192.168.1.102
git clone of main repo in ~/www/testgit2
user: mot

4. host4, Windows Vista, Samba, msysgit
IP: 192.168.1.103
git clone of main repo in c:\shared\testgit3
user: ataga
```

I start a new main repo:

```
cd /var/www/testgit1
git init
```

Now, a lot of questions:

Which groups and users do I have to create?
How to set up required ssh keys?
(I'm playing with gitosis, but with no success by now.)

How to make the main repo visible to other hosts?

How to clone this repo on the hosts?

How to pull changes from others to main repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had to learn some new things to do this.

I used `gitolite` to set up git server. Everything is described in the [gitolite docs](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/tree/master/doc/). The most important thing was to set up *password-less* access via `ssh`.